# Cygwin/SSH Over Corporate Proxy 

Tags: ssh, dns, proxy, cygwin

So I can't SSH outside the corporate firewall to my personal development environment.  It's a Windows shop.  I use Cygwin and bash so I can actually get work done.  SSH doesn't work.

I installed corkscrew with Cygwin.  I have the following in my ~/.ssh/config:

```
ProxyCommand corkscrew _proxy_ _port_ %h %p
```

Executing this at bash:

```
ssh _user_@_host_._tld_
```

Gets me:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname _host_._tld_: hostname nor servname provided, or not known
```

OK, so I try to debug it:

```
ssh -vvv _user_@_host_._tld_
```

Which nets me an extra:

```
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
```

That's as far as I can get.

I understand that there's a lot of variables at play.  I just need a pointer in the right direction.  What is ssh trying to use as a DNS server?  Where would I set that in a Cygwin install?  How does Internet Explorer resolve hostnames outside the corporate LAN?

I would like to use Cygwin without PuTTY for simplicity, but if there's no way, I'll use PuTTY.

Comment: I made a quick test under Linux and didn't find any DNS request made by ssh on the target host. The next `-vvv` line after the one you posted is `debug1: Executing proxy command: …`. It may help if you post the whole `ssh -vvv` trace and your whole `~/.ssh/config`, obscuring only the minimum necessary for privacy.

Comment: Does `_host_` look somewhat like an IP address (e.g. beginning with a letter)? In case it matters, I suggest you obscure host names by replacing each letter by `z` and each digit by `9` (and leave any `-` and `.` unchanged).

Comment: So today, after a reboot, I'm getting a totally different debug trace. I didn't get a <code>debug1: Executing proxy command: ...</code> yesterday.  Maybe it's because I changed my ~/.ssh/config and needed to restart some process or another.  I did kill my Cygwin bash session yesterday, but that didn't do it.  Now I'm getting complaints about my crytographic key files (that I used ssh-user-config to generate, BTW...).  But that's a totally different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for me, a reboot got around this DNS issue.  If you've changed your ~/.ssh/config file, and it's not working, try rebooting, at least under Cygwin.

I'm still getting complaints about my cryptographic keys, but that's a totally different question.  :)